# Extract unique values from column in dataframe, grouped by ID

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe data0 with id's and dates like this:

```
id    date
1   2016-10-20
1   2016-10-19
1   2016-10-20
2   2016-10-21
2   2016-10-22
3   2016-10-21
3   2016-10-21
3   2016-10-22
```

Reproduce:

```
data0 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), date = structure(c(17094, 17093, 17094, 17095, 17096, 17095, 17095, 17096), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I summarize dates by id so that I come out with a structure with counts like this? :

```
id  2016-10-19  2016-10-20  2016-10-21  2016-10-22
1       1            2      
2                                 1           1
3                                 2           1
```

Comment: What is said "structure"? A data.frame? a list?

Comment: @hrbrmstr data0 is a data frame. "structure" is from output of dput() but will render a data.frame.

Comment: you do realize you can't have "blanks" in numeric vectors, right? that makes them character vectors. you shld prbly do: `as.data.frame(unclass(table(data0$id, data0$date)))` if you really want a data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data0 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                        date = structure(c(17094, 17093, 17094, 17095, 17096, 17095, 17095, 17096), class = "Date")),
                   .Names = c("id", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Use the built in table function.

```
> table(data0)
   date
id  2016-10-19 2016-10-20 2016-10-21 2016-10-22
  1          1          2          0          0
  2          0          0          1          1
  3          0          0          2          1
```

Comment: Thanks, and to @akrun as well. I was way overthinking this.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around using `xtabs`:

```
data0$col <- 1
xtabs(col~id+date, data0)

#   date
#id  2016-10-19 2016-10-20 2016-10-21 2016-10-22
#  1          1          2          0          0
#  2          0          0          1          1
#  3          0          0          2          1
```

Comment: And without changing the original data: `xtabs(col ~ id + date, transform(data0, col = 1))`